# Paginate the result after search

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

i need your help please hier. i have a table inside a form, and in that table i load data from database in to it. Everything work how i expected, i have also a small plugins to paginate my table on tbody. i'm trying hier to make a live search, and it's working to but the pagination stay always the same and the Result after Search it's showing in one Page with a lot of data, but i want the Result to be also paginated.
i tried this code but it seem strange when i delete the text in '#mysearch' textbox doesn't
returned more data and stay fixed on the first search i did.
i know there is some plugins like dataTable but that make my whole css work destroyed and i have also in that Table somebutton to do some Action but after dataTable they don't work anymore. that way i want to this without dataTable.
PS: i'm hiding first the normal pagination '$('.pagination').hide();' otherwise it will be twice there.

-i'm working with Doctrine and Zend Framework, jquery , bootstrap.

can someone help me please ? or if you have other idea please let me know.

$("#MySearch").keyup ( function () {

```
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    $.each($('table tbody tr td .searchNumber'), function () {

        if ($(this).val().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) == -1) {


            $(this).closest("#sbrow").hide();
        } else {

        $('.pagination').hide();

            $(this).closest("#sbrow").show();

        }

    });
            var x = $('table tbody > tr:not([style*="display: none"])').length;
            var arr = $('table tbody > tr:not([style*="display: none"])');
            $('table tbody').empty().append(arr);

                if (x <= 10) {
                    $('table tbody').paginathing({
                        perPage: 10,
                        limitPagination: 1,
                        insertAfter: '#myForm',
                        pageNumbers: true
                    });

                } else if (x <= 20) {
                    $('table tbody').paginathing({
                        perPage: 10,
                        limitPagination: 2,
                        insertAfter: '#myForm',
                        pageNumbers: true
                    });

                } else if (x <= 30) {
                    $('table tbody').paginathing({
                        perPage: 10,
                        limitPagination: 3,
                        insertAfter: '#myForm',
                        pageNumbers: true
                    });

                } else if (x <= 40) {
                    $('table tbody').paginathing({
                        perPage: 10,
                        limitPagination: 4,
                        insertAfter: '#myForm',
                        pageNumbers: true
                    });

                } else if (x <= 50) {
                    $('table tbody').paginathing({
                        perPage: 10,
                        limitPagination: 5,
                        insertAfter: '#myForm',
                        pageNumbers: true
                    });
                } else {

                    $('table tbody').paginathing({
                        perPage: 10,
                        limitPagination: 6,
                        insertAfter: '#myForm',
                        pageNumbers: true
                    });
                }
});
```

Comment: Consider paging and filtering your backend when you have a very large volume of data. Bring only what you need to Frontend.

Comment: Thank you Rafael for you answer. Do i have to create another table for the result coming from the live search ?

Comment: Create another table (cache) only if you need a lot of performance.
In most applications a "SQL Query" is enough.